# Custom Authentication/Authorization in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

What is the advantage of using Identity and Principal over Custom Membership Provider and Custom RoleProvider?
I have implemented Custom Membership Provider and Custom Role Provider  (after reading this article:
http://www.brianlegg.com/post/2011/05/09/Implementing-your-own-RoleProvider-and-MembershipProvider-in-MVC-3.aspx  )

However,I like to know if using Identity and Principal is a better option. If so, how do i go about

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Membership provider doesn't have anything to do with it.  FormsAuthentication is a provider of IIdentity and Role Provider is an implementation of IPrincipal.  They are pre-written for you.  Membership is just used to do the actual authentication.